# Passing parameters from test methods

Tags: apex, visualforce, code-coverage, parameters

I am facing difficulty in passing parameters to apex method from test method. In apex method, I am getting parameters from my VF page.

Example of Apex Method:

```
public PageReference create_contact() 
{
        String callfrom = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('callfrom');
        
        Contact newCon = new Contact(lastname = 'Anonymous', phone = callfrom);  
        insert newCon;
        
        return null;
}
```

My Test method:

```
static testMethod void testmatchingcontactController()
{
        test.startTest();
        matching_contacts mc = new matching_contacts();
        mc.create_contact();
        test.stopTest();
}
```

On running test method, I get an error that "Argument cannot be null" because the parameter `callfrom` in apex code is provided by Visualforce page in application. I don't know how can I pass it from test method.

Please help if you know solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test method you can do e.g. this:

```
Test.setCurrentPage(Page.YourPageName);
System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('callfrom', 'yourvalue');
```

essentially simulating the missing page so the test can be 100% in Apex.

Comment: In `Page.YourPageName` I will need to provide the name of VF page?

Comment: That method accepts a `PageReference` and the Apex compiler automatically generates that for you under the `Page` symbol for all your Visualforce pages. So yes, substitute your own page name.

Comment: So my VisualForce Page is named as **dashboard**. I have tried `Test.setCurrentPage(Page.dashboard);
ApexPages.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('callfrom', '2209');`. 

But I get an error **Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void currentPageReference() from the type ApexPages**. Could you please identify what's wrong here?

Comment: @Badar My bad; it should be as you had it `System.currentPageReference()`. I've changed above.